# Infinite direct product of rings free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $A$ be a commutative ring (viewed as an $A$-module over itself) that is not a field. Are there some conditions that guarantee that $\prod_{k=0}^\infty A$ is free? What if $A=\mathbf{Z}$ or more generally any pid?

Comment: If $A=\mathbb{Z}$, then $\prod_{k=0}^\infty A$ is not a free module.  See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module).

Comment: Is it free when $A=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: For $A=\mathbb{Z}$ the classical reference is: Specker, Ernst. "Additive Gruppen von Folgen ganzer Zahlen." Portugaliae Mathematica 9.3 (1950): 131-140. The proof also works when $A$ is a PID with at least two prime elements. I'm not sure what happens for $\mathbb{Z}/4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $A$ is a field, then $\prod_\mathbb{N} A$ is certainly free.  I claim that the direct product $\prod_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{Z}_4$ is also free, where $\mathbb{Z}_4 = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

To prove this let
$\{c_i\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ be a basis for $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is some indexing set. For each $i$ let $b_i$ be the corresponding element of $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}_4$.  That is, the entries of $b_i$ are all $0$'s and $1$'s, and agree with the entries of $c_i$.  I claim that $\{b_i\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ is a basis for $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}_4$.

To see this, consider, the following commutative diagram of abelian groups
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\textstyle\bigoplus_\mathcal{I} \mathbb{Z}_2 & \xrightarrow{\times2} & \textstyle\bigoplus_\mathcal{I} \mathbb{Z}_4 & \longrightarrow & \textstyle\bigoplus_\mathcal{I} \mathbb{Z}_2 \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\textstyle\prod_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{Z}_2 & \xrightarrow{\times2} & \textstyle\prod_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{Z}_4 & \longrightarrow & \textstyle\prod_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{array}
$$
where the first and third vertical arrows are determined by the $c_i$'s, and the middle one is determined by the $b_i$'s.  Both rows are short exact sequences and the vertical arrows on the left and right are known to be isomorphisms, so the middle arrow is also an isomorphism by the [short five lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_five_lemma).

The same argument shows that $\prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is free for any prime $p$.  Moreover, we can iterate the argument to prove that $\prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}$ is free for any prime $p$, where $k$ is a power of $2$.

I have no idea whether $\prod_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ is free.

Comment: I have a question: where does "take a basis $\{c_i\}_I$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, then we have an isomorphism $\bigoplus_I\mathbb{Z}\to\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$" fail? What's the difference with the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ case?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field, so all of its modules have bases. The other rings don't but Jim uses the short five lemma to move it up. I believe his argument also works for all $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ (the short exact sequence could be p->p^k->p^(k-1) rather than p^i->p^2i->p^i).

Comment: So I think this works for any artinian local ring. What about the p-adic integers, $\hat {\mathbb{Z}}_p$?

Comment: @JackSchmidt I'm not convinced that the argument works for $p \to p^k \to p^{k-1}$.  How would you make sure that the diagram commutes?

Comment: @JimBelk: I haven't had time to write it down carefully, but I didn't see any difference. However, Ed Enochs mentioned a short proof for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $n\neq 0$: Over such a ring injective=projective, direct products of injectives are injective. Since we can assume $n$ is a prime power by euclid's algorithm, we can assume projective=free, which finishes it. This does not handle $k[x,y]/(x,y)^n$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Very nice!

Comment: Ed also handled artinian local. In the non-local case, I believe he has an example with the direct product projective but not free. I have to brush up on my set theory to verify it. Let me know if we want another question opened for answers like this. I don't think it interests the OP.