# How can one show that ${\rm Hom}\Bigl(\prod\limits_{i\geqslant 1} \Bbb Z,\Bbb Z\Bigr)$ has cardinality less than $2^{\mathfrak c}$?

Tags: modules

I have read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module?rq=1) that it has cardinality $\aleph_0$, which follows from a theorem of Specker, which I couldn't find. I am looking for a less accurate bound to achieve the same conclusion, that $\prod\limits_{i\geqslant 1} \Bbb Z$ is not a free $\Bbb Z$-module. So for example $\leqslant \mathfrak c$ is good, or $<2^{\mathfrak c}$. However, I couldn't devise such a proof, and neither could I find a reference to Specker's proof. Any of those would suffice.

Comment: This is discussed in [this](http://mathoverflow.net/q/10239) MO question/answer.  See also [this one](http://mathoverflow.net/q/46475).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the references for Specker's proof: Specker, Ernst (1950), "Additive Gruppen von Folgen ganzer Zahlen", Portugaliae Math. 9: 131–140, MR 0039719. However, there are many other proofs as well, see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46475/infinite-direct-product-of-the-integers-not-a-free-module-over-the-integers) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46475/infinite-direct-product-of-the-integers-not-a-free-module-over-the-integers). Don Zagier has given a short argument, too: http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Problems.html, second day, algebra, problem 3. Richard Stanley has this an exercise for some of his courses, see his solution [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-ring-ove).

Comment: Wikipedia calls $\prod\limits_{i\geqslant 1} \Bbb Z$ the [Baer–Specker group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baer%E2%80%93Specker_group) and has references to the original papers too.

Comment: Certainly this will do! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative proof to the links provided I found in a problem sheet from a course I am taking, but the idea is slightly similar.

Suppose $F=\prod \Bbb Z$ is free, and let $M$ be the submodule of $x=(x_i)$ such that for each $n$, the set $\{i:2^n\nmid a_i\}$ is finite. Since $\Bbb Z$ is a PID, $M$ is free. Since $\# M=\mathfrak c$, $M\simeq \prod \Bbb Z$. But $M/2M\simeq \bigoplus \Bbb Z_2$ while $F/2F\simeq \prod \Bbb Z_2$, which yields a contradiction.