# Why is $\mathbb Z_p$ a free $\mathbb Z$-module? Equivalently, why is $\mathbb Q_p$ finite dimensional over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, free-modules

I'm looking to understand why $\mathbb Z_p$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module.  According to wikipedia this is because $\mathbb Z_p$ is the ring of integers for the algebraic number field $\mathbb Q_p$.  The proof that such a ring of integers is a free module is easy enough, but it requires that $\mathbb Q_p$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

Can someone explain to me why $\mathbb Q_p$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space?  Or alternatively, explain why $\mathbb Z_p$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module in a way that does not assume that finite dimensionality?

For reference, I take the algebraic viewpoint that $\mathbb Z_p$ is an inverse limit of $\mathbb Z/p^i$ whose elements can be written as power series in $p$ and whose fraction field is $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: $Q_p$ is not finite dimensional over $Q$ (because it is uncountable) so it i hard to explain why it is...

Comment: I don't believe that $\Bbb Z_p$ is free over $\Bbb Z$; certainly $\Bbb Q_p$ is not finite-dimensional over $\Bbb Q_p$.

Comment: And $Q_p$ is not an algebraic number field.

Comment: @ LordSharktheUnknown Another [non-free](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module) $\mathbb{Z}$-module is $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$, but the proof is much less intuitive than yours for $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the simplest nontrivial example of a **free pro-p** group -- that on a single generator .  Thus, for instance, any surjective morphism of a pro-p group onto $\mathbb{Z}_p$ splits, and also, given an element $g$ of an arbitrary pro-p group $G$, we can find a continuous morphism from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $G$ that maps $1$ to $g$.  Could that be the context you were in on that Wikipedia page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\Bbb Z_p$ is not free over $\Bbb Z$. Observe that $(p+1)\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb Z_p$. For a free Abelian group $G$, $mG=G$ for some integer $m>1$
implies that $G=\{0\}$.

Comment: Hmmm, well that explains why I couldn't figure it out, lol.  Now I can't seem to find where on wikipedia I thought I saw that it was free...