# question about p-adic integers.

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, group-cohomology

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denote the p-adic intergers.I know this is torsion-free Abelian group(i.e. It is flat $\mathbb{Z}$ module).

- I think it is not free Abelian group,but I don't know how to prove this.?
- Is
  $Ext^1_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb {Z})\neq 0$？
- First I select a s.e.s $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow \prod\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow^{1-shift}\prod\mathbb{Z} /p^i \mathbb{Z}
  \rightarrow 0$.
  But $Ext^1_{\mathbb Z}(\prod \mathbb {Z},\mathbb{Z}\neq 0$,this can see my top vote.Then how should I do?

I am confused.I need your help.Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\mathbb Z_p$ is $q$-divisible for any prime $q \neq p$. A free abelian group is certainly not $q$-divisible for any prime $q$.

Comment: @MooS nice observation！thank you.

Comment: @MooS Is the second question true?

Comment: For the second question, consider the exact sequence $0\to \mathbb{Z}_p\stackrel{p}{\to}\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ and observe that $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})=0$ and $Ext^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$ to show that your ext is not zero.

Comment: @Mohan thank you very much.the s.e.s you give is very perfect!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2399486/96384