# Is $\mathbb Z _p$ flat $\mathbb Z$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, flatness

> Is  $\mathbb Z _p$ flat  $\mathbb Z$-module?

$\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z $ is not flat over $\mathbb Z$, so I guess it's inverse limit $\mathbb Z /p^m\mathbb Z$ is not flat. But I'm not confident.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: a $\mathbb{Z}$-module is flat iff it is torsion-free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because it is torsion-free ($\mathbb{Z}$-module is flat iff it is torsion free). A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416181/question-about-p-adic-integers)