# Torsion-free precover

Tags: commutative-algebra

Consider R is an integral domain and K is its filed of fractions.
Definition:A linear map $f:T\rightarrow M$ where T is torsion-free module is called a torsion-free precover of M if for every torsion-free module G and linear map $g:G\rightarrow M$,there is a linear map $h:G\rightarrow T$ such that $fh=g$.
[image]

the mistake is in proof of Lemma 4.1.4.
G may not be direct sum of K,since we can consider $\prod K$.
So how to prove Every module has a torsion-free precover?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error.  A torsion-free divisible $R$-module $G$ is the same thing as a $K$-module, also known as a $K$-vector space.  The fact that such a $G$ is a direct sum of modules isomorphic to $K$ is just the statement that every $K$-vector space has a basis.

Comment: But $\prod K$ is not direct sum of copies of K$

Comment: Sure it is.  It's a vector space, so it has a basis.

Comment: so how to explain $\prod K$is not free K module

Comment: It is a free $K$-module.

Comment: I don't know what your statement of "Baer's theorem" is, but it only applies to certain rings, and fields are not included among them.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module

Comment: yeah ，I think you are right

Comment: thank you，I understand