# Chain groups/ Cochain groups that are not free

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In usual cases, the chain group and cochain group in homology/cohomology are free, where the basis are n-simplices and elementary cochains respectively.
(Is that correct? I am not very sure about cohomology.)

Are there cases that the chain/cochain groups are not free?

For instance, bounded cohomology, I think the bounded cochain group is not free?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cochain groups are actually very often not free.  Indeed, if $X$ is a space, then the group of singular $n$-cochains on $X$ is a product $\prod\mathbb{Z}$, with one factor for each singular $n$-simplex in $X$.  For most spaces $X$, there are infinitely many singular simplices in $X$, so this product is an infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, which [is not a free abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module).