# Can $Hom(G,\mathbb{Z})$ have torsion element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian element. If $G$ is a f.g. $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then $Hom(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is either a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module or $0$. But what if $G$ is not f.g.? Can it have  torsion elements?

Comment: What do you think? What did you try? How do you prove that $\text{Hom}(G, \mathbb{Z})$ is free for finitely generated $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition on $Hom (A, B)$ is pointwise. Therefore if $f\in Hom (A, B)$ is of finite order then so is $f(x)$ for all $x\in A$.

In the particular case of $B=\mathbb{Z}$ (or any other torsion free group) this implies that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$, i.e. $f$ is the neutral element.

Answer (score 2):

The group $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{Z})$ embeds in $\mathbb{Z}^G$, direct product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot have torsion elements, which is what the other answers address.

But it may not be free. For instance, if $G:=\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathrm{Hom}(G;\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \prod_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$, [which is not free](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module).