# How prove a group is not free abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Anyone can give me a hint please?

"Show $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not a free-abelian group"

Comment: This is quite challenging to prove from scratch.  Do you have some tools you've learned that you might use?

Comment: You can find a full proof (not just a hint) at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module.

Comment: You don't give enough information to give you a hint