# Freely generated module

Tags: modules, finitely-generated

A very basic question but given an $R$-module $M$, if $S \subseteq M$ generates $M$ freely, must $S$ necessarily be finite or can it be infinite?

Comment: Well, what is the definition of "freely generated" and what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can be infinite. If you like, by definition an $R$-module $M$ is freely generated by a subset $S$ exactly when when the map $\bigoplus\limits_{s \in S}R \to M$ defined by $1_s \mapsto s$ for any $s \in S$ is an isomorphism. So e.g. if $R$ is any nonzero ring and $M = \bigoplus\limits_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} R$ (a *direct sum*) then $M$ is freely generated by an infinite (in this case countable) subset.

Though be careful: famously e.g. the *direct product* $\prod\limits_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}$ is not a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module).